# How does count become 5 here?

Tags: c++

I am learning the use of get() and put() in c++. I have the following two doubts:

1. As we are in the while loop, why don't the characters get printed as soon as I enter them as there is a put right after the get?
2. Why does count has the value 5 instead of 4? When I hit the Enter key, I will exit the loop(at least that's what I understand). So we have count = 4 when the loop ends.

Here is the code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    
    int count = 0;
    char ch;
    
    cout << "Input text\n";
    
    while(ch != '\n') {
        
        cin.get(ch);
        cout.put(ch);
        count++;
    }
    
    cout << endl << count;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Any kind of help is really appreciated. Please consider me a beginner in C++. Thanks.

Comment: `char ch;` You start with an uninitialized `ch`. Then `count++;` you increment the counter before checking that `ch != '\n'`.

Comment: @Oshada I mean it gives one extra count. For example, if I enter abcd, i get 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop first enters `cin.get()` and does not continue until you enter all your 4 characters. It has to have a new line to continue. After you enter all your 4 characters, the loop continues and reads the characters one by one.

The value of `count` is 5 because it also gets incremented when you enter the new line. The new line is also a character. Your input is not `abcd` but `abcd\n`.  And after it completes that last iteration, it checks the condition and sees that the last character is a new line and this is when it terminates.